# Find the view controller for a UIView / set it to a different one

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I apologize if this is a stupid question but I just can't seem to understand how the view controllers work in xcode. I added a view controller to my storyboard but when I try to add a button on it and a label that will be updated when that button is clicked, nothing is working. It will let me create an action for the button but the action won't do anything. It also won't let me add an outlet for the label so what I think is going on is that the view controller that I made isn't actually the one responsible view controller element on the storyboard (whose custom class is UIView and I can't change it the view controller that I made). The only other view controller file in the project also won't accept outlets for the label when I control drag from the storyboard so I really am not sure what is going on and how I can go about fixing it. Any and all help would be appreciated. I am really new to Swift so apologies again if this is a stupid question please bear with me.

[image]

Comment: can you show images ? how you assigning new controller ? are you using storyboard ?

Comment: I added the storyboard with the view controller and the class showing as UIView. Another stackoverflow post that I looked at suggested to change the class to UIViewController but that's not an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an image to help you. If you tap inside the controller it will take you to the view but if you tap on the controller it will take you to the `UIViewController` file.

[image]